# is HashSet is implemented via a HashMap instance

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I am wondering since the HashSet is implemented via a HashMap instance , what would be the key that would be used to put data into HashSet.

i gone through the link http://www.coderanch.com/t/251832/Programmer-Certification-SCJP/certification/Difference-HashMap-HashSet...

which i dint understood properly..
Can anybody help me to understand it better

Comment: You could easily answer this yourself by looking at the source code!!

Answer (score 6):

From the source:

```
// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();


public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Comment: Interesting; I had always just assumed it would do put(e,e).

Comment: why not just use a null value?

Comment: @dertoni: I didn't write it, of course, but my guess would be that they wanted to allow for a different backing implementation of HashMap, which would not be guaranteed to permit null values.

Answer (score 5):

the key would be the object that went into the hashset itself since keys of maps are sets.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "keys of maps are sets"?

Comment: a key of a map will always map to the same value, so all map keys have to be unique. So by definition, they're sets.

Comment: Or if you look at Map.keySet() it returns a Set.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the object you add to the `HashSet` as a key of the `HashMap`. That way the `add`, `remove`, and `contains` run in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes ([source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#93)). HashSet is essentially an interface to a HashMap's keySet.

```
   /**
    * HashSet is an implementation of a Set. All optional operations (adding and
    * removing) are supported. The elements can be any objects.
    */
   public class HashSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> implements Set<E>, Cloneable,
           Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -5024744406713321676L;

       transient HashMap<E, HashSet<E>> backingMap; // right here!
```